# Bootstrap navbar not working on Chrome, works everywhere else

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I'm making a website using this theme (you can see the code here):

https://bootstrapthemes.co/item/jwood-photography-portfolio-html-landing-page-template/

But there's a problem: the navbar doesn't work on Chrome. It looks good but doesn't take you anywhere when clicked. It works perfectly on IE.

Can you help me, where's the problem with this? I think it worked when i downloaded the theme a couple weeks ago. I haven't made any changes to the code that would effect the navbar. Clearing browser cache doesn't help.

The live preview page has the same problem:

https://bootstrapthemes.co/demo/html/one-page-portfolio-landing-page/

Comment: Your one seems to work on Chrome, but not the Live Preview page...

Comment: What's working on Chrome? The live preview page nor the code downloaded from the page isn't working for me

Comment: Oops sorry, I thought that Bootstrap Themes was your site.

Answer (score 2):

This might be related to [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/ux2yx4TWu5o;context-place=topicsearchin/chrome/category$3Areport-a-problem-and-get-troubleshooting-help%7Csort:relevance%7Cspell:false) issue.

Also I didn't found any selector with id `navbar-collapse` in main.js file.

Event is bound to `$('#navbar-collapse')` instead of `$('.navbar-collapse')`

By changing the selector it will work in chrome.